# Confidence Estimate in classification (or regression)

Tags: algorithms, classification, svm

I am using the sklearn SVC algorithm in the context of a time series, classifying the next time step as either being a positive increase or a negative increase.

My SVC is, right now, predicting the change with 65% accuracy...

Obviously, some of the predictions are going to be more certain than others.  Is there a way to determine the level of confidence of a support vector classification?

And if not, is there a classification or regression system that takes an n-dimensional array of input data, and will make a prediction with a confidence score?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  1. What's a SVC?  Is it the same thing as a [SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)?  2. Note that there might be a larger community of folks able to answer your question at [Stats.SE].  Don't cross-post on both places, but if you'd like to see your question migrated there, just flag your question for moderator attention and ask for it to be moved.  I do emphasize your question *is* on-topic here and is OK to stay here if you prefer; just wanted to mention the option, as you might be more likely to get a good answer over there.

Comment: Thanks man...will do.   SVC is just "Support Vector Classification.."